# Hartree Fock method

Tags: reference-request, hartree-fock

Currently, I'm studying (again from zero and more in detail) Hartree Fock (HF) method, specifically the Restricted Hartree Fock (RHF).
I'm following two books:
"Introduction to Computational Chemistry" (Frank Jensen 2nd edition)
"Computational Chemistry, Introduction to the Theory and Applications of Molecular Quantum Mechanics" (Errol G. Lewars 2nd edition)

Both books describe the method starting from the Slater determinant of N (N = n° of electrons) Molecular Orbitals (MOs), in this way all the MOs are occupied. Then they generalize to the case where we have M > N MOs, so some will be empty.
But this last point is not well explained, I would like to understand this passage in detail, so I ask for an explanation or some references (books or articles ...).

Comment: I have read the former book, and I don't think Jensen assumed that "all the MOs are occupied" in any part of his derivation. This is likely a misunderstanding. If you are sure he did assume this, could you please quote the part that says this?

Comment: @wzkchem5 Until page 92 the Slater determinant is supposed to be constructed by N MOs, and the HF equations are in fact N. Until page 92 there is no summation over occupied MOs but only summation over all electrons. On page 94 he substitutes the MOs with a linear combination of basis set functions, then he says "Multiplying from the left by a specific basis function and integrating yields the Roothaan–Hall equations" assuming now that there are M (M = n° of basis functions) MOs, and in fact, the summation over occupied orbitals appear in page 95 for the first time.

Comment: You should look at Szabo-Ostlund. Even though a lot of the book is outdated (it is from the early 1980s), it is unbeatable in its clarity. It also discusses such issues as linear dependence in the basis set, which many books still omit or get wrong...

Comment: @SusiLehtola Ok thank you, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: I gave my +1 a long time ago, but did the comment by Susi help? Please update us!

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes, yes. Basically, when you pass from the integrodifferential HF equation to the Roothaan equations, you want your matrix to be a square matrix. For this reason, you calculate more MOs that will be empty and are called virtual orbitals. If you are interested in theoretical chemistry, I suggest this book: Trygve Helgaker, Poul Jorgensen, Jeppe Olsen - Molecular Electronic-Structure Theory-Wiley (2013). It's excellent.

Comment: @Al1010 are you able to write an answer now? If not, what part of the original question are you still not able to answer?

Comment: @NikeDattani I told you the answer. Moreover, you can do the same thing even with the integrodifferential HF equation when solved in the SCF way. Once you substitute the occupied MOs in the Fock operator, it becomes just an effective one-electron operator, and you can find infinite eigenstates.
If you use a finite basis, you want to have a total number of MOs equal to the basis set size. This is why virtual orbitals are introduced. (Then of course virtual MOs are used in all post-HF methods)

Comment: @NikeDattani if you want the full derivation in detail, you can find it in "Trygve Helgaker, Poul Jorgensen, Jeppe Olsen - Molecular Electronic-Structure Theory-Wiley (2013)" page 458

Comment: @NikeDattani subsection 10.6 The Roothaan-Hall self-consistent field equations

Comment: I believe Nike means that it would be potentially useful to other users if you self-answered your question in the answer box, rather than in the comments.